# How can I draw this figure about Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-pic

[image]

How can I draw this figure about Hidden Markov Model?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us the code you have tried so far ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For exercise (how to draw dashed line and use empty cells):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]  
X_1 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"'] 
    &   X_2 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"']  
        &   X_3 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"']  
            &   \dots  \ar[r, "A"] 
                &   X_{T-1} \ar[dd, "B"']       \\
\arrow[rrrr, dashed, -,  
       start anchor={[shift={(-3ex,2ex)}]north west},
       end anchor  ={[shift={( 3ex,2ex)}]north east}]
    &   &   &   &                               \\
    &   &   &   \dotsm  &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Complete reproduction of presented images:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]
\text{Markov process:}
    &   X_0 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"']
        &   X_1 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"']
            &   X_2 \ar[r, "A"] \ar[dd, "B"']
                &   \dots  \ar[r, "A"]
                    &   X_{T-1} \ar[dd, "B"']       \\
    &   \arrow[rrrr, dashed, -,
           start anchor={[shift={(-3ex,2ex)}]north west},
           end anchor  ={[shift={( 3ex,2ex)}]north east}]
    &   &   &   &   &                               \\
\text{Observations:}
    &   \mathcal{O}_0
        &   \mathcal{O}_1
            &   \mathcal{O}_2
                &   \dotsm
                    &   \mathcal{O}_{T-1}           \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With a normal `matrix of math nodes`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep=2em,row sep=4em] (m) {
\text{Markov process}: &
 X_0 & X_1 & X_2 & \cdots & X_{T-1}\\
\text{Observations}: & 
 \mathcal{O}_0 & \mathcal{O}_1 & \mathcal{O}_2 & \cdots & \mathcal{O}_{T-1}\\
};
\foreach \X in {2,3,4,5}
{\draw[-latex] (m-1-\X) -- (m-1-\the\numexpr\X+1) node[midway,above]{$A$};
\ifnum\X=5
\draw[-latex] (m-1-6) -- (m-2-6) node[pos=0.6,left]{$B$};
\else
\draw[-latex] (m-1-\X) -- (m-2-\X) node[pos=0.6,left]{$B$};
\fi}
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=1ex]m.east) -- ([yshift=1ex]m.east-|m-1-1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]